# Listbox Separator

Tags: c#, listbox, separator

What's the best way to divide listbox items into groups? I've tried using Environment.NewLine but there's no good way of removing without selecting it.

I need to have a listbox with items divided as customers order. The chef needs to prepare these items, select on an item when it's done until the whole group of order is finished. There's "Finish" button that will remove the selected group but the whitespace will remain.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: The `ListBox` isn't built for that.  Probably you should use a `ListView` with grouping turned on.  You can then put each item into a group and that will separate them for you.

Comment: Are you using WPF or Windows Forms? This question would be improved by another tag.

Comment: It's windows forms. I'll go with listview

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Forms `ListBox` control doesn't have such functionality.

Your first option is to use another control, which you may find on the web (I don't have any control I know in mind).

Another option would be to custom draw the `Listbox` items. When you hit a specific identifier on the start of the item, you can draw the separator. This will need some knowledge GDI+ though.

Read [How to: Create an Owner-Drawn List Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229679(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Thanks but no need to be fab :)